# Chrome Javascript date comparison false error

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I'm using javascript and Chrome (Windows 44.0.2403.107 m (64-bit)).
All of the following date comparison code returns false.

```
console.log(new Date('29-07-2015') < new Date('01-01-2016'));
console.log(new Date('29-07-2015').getTime() < new Date('01-01-2016').getTime());
console.log('29-07-2015' < '01-01-2016');
```

If I put first date as 01-01-2015 and second date in the same year then I get a valid answer in all above codes. Is there anything I have missed? Thank you :)

FOUND THE ANSWER THANK YOU @WhiteHat :)

```
console.log(new Date('29-07-2015') < new Date('01-01-2016')); //false
console.log(new Date('07-29-2015') < new Date('01-01-2016')); //true
```

Comment: Type `new Date('29-07-2015')` into the console => `Invalid Date`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

what is your locale? try formatting your dates as mm-dd-yyyy...

```
console.log(new Date('29-07-2015') < new Date('01-01-2016')); //false
console.log(new Date('07-29-2015') < new Date('01-01-2016')); //true
```